# Shortcut keys for changing input source not working in Login screen

Tags: 14.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys, login-screen

I use `Shift+Alt` shortcut to change the input source language and it works fine everywhere except the login screen, and when waking up from suspend. Is this a bug or am I missing something?

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a while the problem was fixed on its own! Probably an update fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal and run:

```
gksu gedit /etc/default/keyboard
```

(or use some other text editor)

Do following changes in the file:

```
XKBLAYOUT="de,us"
XKBVARIANT=""
XKBOPTIONS="grp:alt_shift_toggle"
```

(Replace de,us with your languages)

Restart and try again.

Comment: Thanks but it didn't work